# Passing SQL column names through html input - unwise/unsafe?

Tags: php, sql, input

I'm trying to make a form easy to save using a PHP function.

The HTML looks like:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="form[name]"/>
<input type="text" name="form[lastname]"/>
```

The function for inserting/updating the database contains something like

```
$data = $_POST['form'];    
foreach($data as $column => $value){
// Creating the SQL statement using $column & $value
}
```

The table will be passed in php, not through HTML.

Should i be afraid of passing the column names through HTML?

Comment: depends on how you're going to insert the values to your database. That cannot be said just based on the information you provided.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little dangerous, because it provides an attacker with exactly what to go for, but most of the time those fields are pretty standard, so it's not like people have to guess too much...if you did have a sql injection vulnerability they could find that stuff out anyway.

So long as you're using prepared statements (I prefer this method, there are others) and validating inputs you should be fine.